# Variable in Generate Rows step in PDI

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I want to use variable in 'Generate rows' step in Pentaho. How can i use it. I want to give a file path in a 'Value' field but that should not be static so that i can pass this value into my csv input.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question (see [@mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/968671/mat)'s comment), but as far as I can understand it, I wonder if you really need a `Generate Rows`.

The `CSV Input File` can read the `file name` from a variable. If you look near this field you'll see a small 'S' in a blue diamond shape. It means that you can put a variable in it, in the format `${var_name}`.

This suppose that your variable is indeed a variable, as opposed to a field. You can get the list of variables by pressing on `Ctrl+Space` on any input box near the 'S' in blue diamond shape. You can add a variable either in defining in a previous job, either in the parameter list [Right-click anywhere and select `Parameters`], either by editing the `kettle.properties` [on the top menu `Edit`], either by specifying the variable value on the small panel that is presented to you each time you want to run a transformation.

With a `Generate Rows`, you define a `field` and there is no way to use a field for the filename in a `CVS Input file`. You can however use a field in a `Text file input` with the `Accept file name from an other step` check box, and telling spoon from which step and from which field. If you use this step, specify on the `Content` tab that the `filetype` is CSV.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "for" javascript lang step and get variable to generate rows,